# making computed properties binding aware in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

If I use a computed property within a template, how do I make the template know that know that state has changed in a way that affects that computed value?

For instance, if I was displaying two numbers that could be incremented, and their sum, as shown below

```javascript
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    x:0,
    y:0,
    sum: function(){return this.get("x") + this.get("y");}.property("content.sum"),
    incX: function(){ this.set("x", this.x+1);},
    incY: function(){ this.set("y", this.y+1);},
});
```

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <button {{action "incX"}}> {{x}} </button>
  <button {{action "incY"}}> {{y}} </button>
  <p> {{sum}} </p>
</script>
```

The x and y values will be updated in the display, but the sum will not be updated. How do I tell handlebars/ember that sum is dependent on x and y?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arguments for the computed property (`.property(_)`) are not what you want access to, but for specifying which values the computed property should observe and recompute when any of these values change.

In your case:

```
sum: function() {
    return this.get("x") + this.get("y");
}
.property("x", "y")
```

Comment: Correct - the arguments in the `property` should be the properties that this computed property that is relying on, and should be notified. Check out the doc: http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/